# ng-click accessing other element values

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to access the value of an input when clicking on a button:

Controller:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.test = function(val) {
    alert(val);
  }
});
```

HTML:

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <input type="text" id="inputText">
    <button type="button" ng-click="test(document.getElementById('inputText').value)">Test</button>
</body>
```

But 'undefined' is what comes up in the alert. How is this achieved in angular?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With `ng-model` on the desired `input`

```
<input type="text" id="inputText" ng-model="myInput">
<button type="button" ng-click="test(myInput)">Test</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

But if you switch the order like that

```
<button type="button" ng-click="test(myInput)">Test<//button>

<input type="text" id="inputText" ng-model="myInput">
```

you won't get the value of `myInput`. In this case you see it weird! by the way if you put your button in the div bar, maybe you will get this issue

Comment: Olla ! I get the solution. Put in your controller   

...
angular.element(document.getElementById('inputText'));
...